# TASCAM DR-100 MKII Vs DR-40??

Tags: portable-recorder, tascam

Hey guys. I had a query about which one's better. performance wise, battery wise, and frequency range wise. I have boiled down to these two and i am really confused as to which one to go for. Also could any of you suggest any better portable recorders in the range of $300- $500? 
Thank you.

Comment: Dr 40: condenser mics / Dr100MKII: dinamic mics????

Comment: more of a question, I have used the DR100 MKii for years via a gear sharing and I do vouch for it! love it,! the on board pre amps with a condenser/shotgun mic do have a fair bit of noise but recently I have been using it with a friends Azden external mixer and Sennheiser mic., very good combo! I'm looking at getting my own equipment so I don't need to share with friends as much these days. So, do the DR40 and DR100 have the same line in frequency and quality control as eachother or is one superior than the other in that regard too? I do not intend to go direct in to the recorder as the pre am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the Tascam DR40 and I must say its pretty good. Its in a lot of ways similar to the Zoom H4N, but is comparatively cheaper. I have used both, DR100 and DR40 and sound quality wise I feel there's not much of a difference between the DR100 and the DR40. Just that the DR100 has more functions (sometimes it feels that its more than what you actually need). I'd give a +1 to the DR40 for its adjustable mic positions which you cannot do in the DR100. If you are just starting out in field recording, then I think the DR40 would be a good choice and for the price that you get it, its awesome. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I have the Tascam DR-100 MKII and it's brilliant. The inbuilt mics are surprisingly good, the SNR is impressive. Battery-life of the rechargeable battery seems pretty decent, I haven't tested it out fully yet or tried it with phantom power on, but so far so good. The build quality is superb; sturdy metal casing, the buttons and wheel feel nice. It even comes with a wireless remote!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Skarik, I also use the Tascam and its great.  The built-in mics are better then I expected, I have used it for all manner of recording and I have not been disappointed.  You also get the flexibility to hook up your own mics as well.

Only draw back for me is you can't record using the built-in mics at the same time as an external mic.  In my opinion that would have been great so you can record multiple responses to a sound without having to do another take.

Answer (score 2):

I've just got a Roland R-26 mainly for recording foley and so far I've not been disappointed. It comes with 2 directional and 2 omni-direction mics built in. Jigsaw are currently doing a deal where you get the carry case and dead kitten worth £75 included in the price (£386).

It records in mp3 or WAV, up to 96 KHz, 24-bit. It also has 2 analog ins for additional mics (XLR or jack) and another mini-jack on the side for another mic. Files save onto an SD card and you could even use this an an interface for you pc/mac. Check out the link below!

http://www.jigsaw24.com/product-details/x952aae/roland-r-26-usb-portable-recorder-and-carry-case-bundle

Comment: we tested it, and we found the limiter very noisy, like every portable roland stuff. shame..:/ that was the reason why i choose the zoomH4n.

Comment: @bohitomi I find that extremely hard to agree with, having used both with internal and external mics of DPA and Sennheiser variety (and gain staging properly so you're not riding against the limiter!).

Answer (score 2):

I own a DR-40 and it rocks. I can't do it right now, but I will post some links with recordings from it. Battery lasts a lot, I've actually utilized with a co-worker and he owns de Zoom H4n, and we have both reached the conclusion that the DR-40 is better, performance wise; sound quality wise should be more of a subjective answer which I would rather leave to your own, but I will come back with the links to it!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I've used both but I own a DR-100mkII and for me it is definitely the better choice. The pre's are much better and I like the added features such as the omni mic's. For me, one of the biggest differences is the gain control - with the DR-40 you cannot get around the button noises when changing gain. I used to hate listening back to the recordings and hearing the button presses. The gain wheel on the DR-100mkII is a saviour!

There's a lot of great advice on this thread!